# How to add new default value from latest value summed with integer where value had both string and integer

Tags: qgis-3

I have a current field value with both integer and string i.e. PL000001. This is to identify a pole numbers id. So I am looking for an expression for when I add new attribute to add to the default value, whereas in the latest or highest value in this case PL000001 is included in the default value expression, where the new value will be PL000002.

```
Highest Value - PL000001

New Value/Attribute = Highest Value + 1 = PL000002
```